# Suppress 802.1X Dialog on OS X

Tags: macos, 802.1x

I frequently connect my MacBook to a wired network that it detects as 802.1X.

However the network doesn't actually require any authentication, and I am able to press Cancel on the dialog that shows up (pictured below) and connect to the network without any further issue.

The dialog shows up though every time I reconnect to the network, and I have to press cancel every time.

Is there any way to suppress this dialog from showing up?

[image: 802.1X Dialog]

Comment: The real fix is to track down what's sending the spurious 802.1X identity request packets on your network and fix that.

Comment: Or connect your cardreader?